# Debian 8 + supervisor

Tags: python, linux, debian

My OS is Debian 8.

I want to use supervisor to restart my python script:

```
/home/username/prog/test.py

import time
while True:
    print('I am alive.')
    time.sleep(1)
```

My config file:

```
/etc/supervisor/conf.d/testapp.conf

[program:testapp]
command=/usr/bin/python3 /home/username/prog/test.py > output.txt
autostart=true
autorestart=true
stderr_logfile=/home/username/prog/long.err.log
stdout_logfile=/home/username/prog/long.out.log
```

But output.txt is empty..

All permisions is ok.

Comment: not really a programming Q, but is this a typo? `command=/usr/bin/python3 /home/username/prog/test.py > output .txt` (note the space between `output` and `.txt` )? Good luck.

Comment: thanks, it's a typo. dont working

Comment: Have you considered adding `#!/usr/bin/env python` to your script and set the executable flag? You also execute it using `crontab`